# "We never had a fight" - in Italian (Terence Hill's spech on Bud Spencer's funeral)

Tags: word-meaning

Terence Hill told a story on the funeral of his friend, Bud Spencer, last week - [video (with hungarian subtitle)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjuEmU8iP5Y).

According to the hungarian subtitle, Bud used to repeat a phrase in Italian, which in English might mean:

> We never had a fight.

and

> We really never had a fight.

I can not understand the exact words by Terence Hill, what Bud had used to say:

> Non abbiamo...

Could you please help me finish the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentences that, according to Terence Hill, Bud Spencer used to say are:

> Non abbiamo mai litigato

and

> Non abbiamo proprio mai litigato.